# Deep linking of URL in a google calendar invitation email is not working

Tags: android, url, google-calendar-api, deep-linking, icalendar

Created an event from Android native calendar by adding a URL(on click of which I intend to open my application) in "Description/Notes" field. Then added some gmail contacts as "Invitees" to the event and Saved the event. The event was successfully created and invitation was sent to the gmail contacts I invited.
The recipients received the invitation via gmail.
When they try to click the URL that I added in description, it is redirected to browser. But that has to open my application in recipient's phone, as I have done deep linking of that URL into my application.

PS : Clicking of this URL from a normal mail opens the application. But clicking it from google calendar invitation mail redirects to browser and does not open application.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you able to find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt show the code. But if it is not going inside app I guess you didnt register receiver to catch it.
Example

```
<receiver
   android:name=".NativeEventChangeReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
<data android:scheme="content"/>
<data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```